# How to increase the adhesive grip of a Magic Keyboard 2 rubber feet?

Tags: keyboard, hardware

The "rubber" feet under an Apple Magic Keyboard 2 (MLA22D/A) are too slippery.

What's the simplest, ideally reversible, way to increase the adhesive power of the rubber feet without ruining what is underneath the external keyboard, or a way to augment them with different anti-skid pads, feet, rubbers?

Comment: Get a [silicone non-slip cutting mat](https://amzn.to/2rnDgOY) and cut it to size.  It's flexible, customizable, and portable.

Answer (score 4):

The rubber feet on Apple's newer keyboards are teeny, tiny, little hard bumps, and they don't prevent the keyboard from sliding around on some types of surfaces at all (like they should). Judging from the dirt on mine they look like in addition to being very hard plastic they also only have a contact area of **one square millimeter**.

I think the easiest, least destructive, and cheapest way would be to buy new soft rubber feet. The main point would be to make sure they are *soft*, not hard. Also, the larger the rubber feet, the more force they will be able to resist when being pushed around.

I found two products on Amazon that could do the job just fine. If you don't mind the shape of [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004670VZM) rubber feet, they are a good solution:

[image]

but if you prefer to have a larger contact area, [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B018Q4XSP0) would be a great choice:

[image]

Comment: These links might be quite handy, but my network is prohibiting me from accessing them. A bit more of description fro what awaits behind these links might help me and others to find these products better…

Comment: @LangLangC I have edited the answer to add visual descriptions for the links.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Thx, great. Those outbound obfuscators really left me quite clueless. That is better now. But I think the OP really should add a little bit more of description: what is the product, what does it do, and arguably: how good are these (personal experience?). &"Visual"= visually impaired people are not much wiser now.  But that is SE-answer wise. Personally, I am delighted about these options to consider :) Thx again.

Comment: I tried the non-dampening bumpers (first Amazon link) and **they didn't work at all** on the laminate surface of my keyboard tray. I'll try the silicone rubber feet next.