# Tilting up magic keyboard for better ergonomics

Tags: keyboard

I have the most recent [Magic Keyboard](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MQ052LL/A/magic-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-us-english-silver) and I find it hard to type on it as it lays very flat on my desk.

- I'd like to have an angle on the keyboard for typing; other wireless keyboards have little "feet" that fold out to enable the user to tilt the top upwards

For now, I have taped two pencils under the keyboard for some angle which kinda works.

- Is there a product / better way to fix the keyboard up that way?

(Keyboard was given to me at work, not really an option to switch)

Comment: This is just a suggestion, because I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for, so that's why it's not an answer.  Take a look at [this DIY setup](http://www.instructables.com/id/Tilt-your-Aluminum-Apple-Keyboard/), it might work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for a semi-permanent setup:

- get two rubber erasers (or [corks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bung) from a wine bottle, as long it those made from real cork wood), these provide enough drag resistance so it does not slide too much.
- cut them to the desired height and angle. This requires some experimentation and tinkering. If the erasers are big enough this might actually be enough. Place them under the back sie of the keyboard.
- use a non too permanent double-sided adhesive strip to make this reversably permanent (powerstrips for posters work quite well; if removed they won't leave a trace of manipulation)

This is the most flexible solution that adapts most easily too almost any angle you like.

Also, from a [related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/324578/how-to-increase-the-adhesive-grip-of-a-magic-keyboard-2-rubber-feet):

> Get a [silicone non-slip cutting mat](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/324578/how-to-increase-the-adhesive-grip-of-a-magic-keyboard-2-rubber-feet) and cut it to size. It's flexible, customizable, and portable.
>   <sub>(Allan's comment)</sub>

Cutting this so that it only slips under one (back-)side may work for you.

Or, like the answer there seemed to suggest: you might go for a permanent solution and attach self-adhesive rubber feet, buy them according to your desired angle.

Comment: Thanks, that cutting mat is a really good idea, I'll give that a try!